# Jackson JSON processor failure

Tags: java, android, json, object, jackson

I have a method in a class:

```
public MyClass readMyObject(Activity activity) {
        MyClass myClass = null;
        try {
            myClass = new MyClass();
            SharedPreferences prefs = activity.getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("myClass", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            String preferences = prefs.getString("myClass", "0");
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            byte[] byteTemp = mapper.readValue(preferences, byte[].class);
            ByteArrayInputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(byteTemp);
            ObjectInputStream is = new ObjectInputStream(in);
            myClass = (MyClass) is.readObject();
            } catch (JsonParseException e) {
            } catch (IOException e) {
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            }
        return myClass;
    }
```

Following is the exception i am getting

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper;
```

I use:

- jackson-core-2.4.2.jar
- jackson-annotations-2.4.2.jar
- jackson-databind-2.4.2.jar

The target of my app is Android 5.0. 
Thank you!

Comment: Hmm, so your code compiles, and yet at runtime a core class of Jackson isn't found? Sounds like a build system problem to me, not a Java problem

Comment: If i don't include appCompat_v7 and android-support-v4.jar this error doesn't happen...